# Disable or hide apps on android,so that the user can't acces them via ADB

Tags: android, adb

Best StackOverflow users,

I am developing a software that uses ADB (Android Debug Bridge), that will hide or disable an app. So that the end user can't use them. I had a few questions, you would do me a favor to help me.

1. Can you disable or hide an app without root?
2. Is there any other way to achieve this?
3. Is there an way to root the device without tripping the KNOX and without losing the ability to receive OTA updates?

We want don't want to root the device, because we want to encrypt the device and install our company apps and hide/disable the apps that we don't want to deliver to the customers.

Thanks in advance,

A.V.R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, manually rooting all the devices, uninstalling all the 'bloatware' and unneeded applications and then revoking root permissions is the quickest way.

Answer (score 1):

Well as you mentioned you have knox access. Knox itself have methods to disable and hide apps; you may look into standard and customised knox documentation to find the relative methods.

The other approach you can use is to make your app system app and then you may use shell commands to hide or disbale it.

I have already made app relating to same requirement and for me it works on knox using knox methods and for system apps using system signature.

The method to diable or hide apps in knox is using **`appPolicy.setDisableApplication(pkg);`**

in case you want to enable it back the use 
**`appPolicy.setEnableApplication(pkg);`**

for system signed app use ad shell command **`pm disable "your app package name"`** to disable or hide app and to enable it back use  **`pm enable"your app package name"`**